# getting back to previous mode after call ends in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, silent, phone-state-listener, incoming-call

in my app i want to add an option: putting phone on silent mode when a group of specific numbers call(i use database later for this,now try with a number)

here is my code:

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 Context context = null;
 private static final String TAG = "Phone call";
 private ITelephony  telephonyService;

 private String silentNum="+.....";
 AudioManager am,temp;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Log.v(TAG, "Receving....");
  TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
  try {
      am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      temp = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      temp.getRingerMode();

   Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
   Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
   m.setAccessible(true);
   telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
   Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
   String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
   db= new dbhandler(context);
   db.open();
   int ch = db.checkexist("call", phoneNumber, "1");
   if ((phoneNumber != null) && (ch==1)){
   //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
   telephonyService.endCall();
   Log.e("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
   }

   if ((phoneNumber != null) && (phoneNumber.equals(silentNum))){
       am.setRingerMode(0);
       }

       }

  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
```

I also added BroadcastReceiver to my manifest too , now when one of those  number calls,phone get on silent mode.
my problem is i don't know how to get back the previous mode of phone, i don't know when the call is finished

is this the right code for getting back to previous mode?

where should i put it?

```
   switch (temp.getRingerMode()) {
   case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
   Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
   break;
   case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
   Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
   break;
   case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
   Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ((phoneNumber != null) && (phoneNumber.equals(silentNum))){
       am.setRingerMode(0);
       }
else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals
                    (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                // This code will execute when the call's disconnected
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Hang up",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                AudioManager maudio = (AudioManager) context.
                        getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                maudio.setRingerMode
                        (AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

            }
```